# Error adding index to mysqlcluster database table

Tags: mysql

I am using root user (on SQL node) and I cannot alter/modify database tables which are accessed remotely. The database table which are accessed locally can be modified though. To view the concurrently used database i used `show full processlist` . Below is the command/errors occured. How to get past these errors ?

```
 mysql> alter table `sks_staff_office` add index `pid_index` (pid);
    ERROR 1296 (HY000): Got error 156 'Unknown error code' from NDBCLUSTER

    mysql> create ONLINE index pid_index on sks_staff_office(pid);
    ERROR 1296 (HY000): Got error 156 'Unknown error code' from NDBCLUSTER

    mysql> alter online table `sks_staff_office` add index `pid_index` (pid);
    ERROR 1296 (HY000): Got error 156 'Unknown error code' from NDBCLUSTER
```

Thank you.

Comment: Check this [Bug #21881](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=21881)

Comment: the bug seems to be back in 2006, hope it is fixed now